In excel- sumif command
i want to sum numbers that sit next to a text value in the adjacent cell.
so i want the total for pty, ptn and ext. ive tried using the sumif formula but that does not seem to work as there are multipe colunms possibly? any help greatly appreciated.
=SUMIF(D2:H4,"ptn",D2:H4)



Col1
Col2
Col3
Col4




ptn
8
ext
8


ptn
6
ptn
6


pty
10
pty
10




If applicable, then using GROUPBY():


• Formula used in cell D6
=LET(
     a, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(D2:G4),2),
     GROUPBY(TAKE(a,,1),DROP(a,,1),SUM,,0))


If you don't have access to GROUPBY() then using SUM() or SUMPRODUCT():


• Formula used in cell E6
=SUM(IFERROR((D$2:F$4=D6)*E$2:G$4,0))


The above formula needs to copy down, while the GROUPBY() will return the whole output as one single dynamic array.

Alternatively, using MAP():
=LET(
     a, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(D2:G4),2),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     d, MAP(c,LAMBDA(x,SUM((x=b)*DROP(a,,1)))),
     HSTACK(c,d))


Similarly, with MMULT():
=LET(
     a, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(D2:G4),2),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(b,MMULT(N(b=TOROW(b)),DROP(a,,1)))))


• Or, for better performance for the above, use the following way:
=LET(
     a, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(D2:G4),2),
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, UNIQUE(b),
     SORT(HSTACK(c,MMULT(N(c=TOROW(b)),DROP(a,,1)))))



Further proof that spreadsheet formulas have come a long way since Lotus 1-2-3!

A simple way to apply the SUMIF function in this case:
=SUMIF($D$2:$F$4, "ptn", $E$2:$G$4)

It is important to match the addresses properly.

Excellent, thank you. In my actual sheet there are about 20 colums 10 with text and 10 with numbers so i woul need to id all colums as youve done with the $. Thank you for your help again

$ may not be as important as the fact that the columns of texts and numbers to be summed are shifted by one column.
